# Replace symbols in HTML mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I generated template using HTML mail generator:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
........
<table role="presentation">.......<span style="font-size: 20px;">&#x423;&#x441;&#x43F;&#x435;&#x448;&#x43D;&#x430; &#x440;&#x435;&#x433;&#x438;&#x441;&#x442;&#x440;&#x430;&#x446;&#x438;&#x44F;......</table>
.........
</html>
```

But I need to send different content like name and address into each mail. Currently the text is exceeded as you can see I suppose for compatibility reasons. Is it a good practice to set for example some using value and replace the symbols each time with Java?
Also do you know what is the encoding of the above symbols?
Can you guide me why would be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use template engines for these kind of requirements

There are multiple template engines are available like

1. Apache Velocity
2. Apache FreeMarker
3. Thymeleaf
4. Pebble

But I feel Apache FreeMarker is better. Kindly find below link for details [Apache FreeMarker with Example](https://www.concretepage.com/freemarker/java-freemarker-templates-ftl-tutorial-with-html-example)